# Magento 2 admin panel custom controller actions not working

Tags: magento2, menu

I created a `custom module` in adminportal with custom controller in `magento 2` but the controller action is giving 404 error page can someone help me on this?

mymodule folder structure is

> app/code/Gokulpriya/CustomMenu/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

```
 <?php
namespace Gokulpriya\CustomMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);

        $result->setContents('Hello world');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share all the files of your module.

Comment: Please check your class name.Your controller name is Test but you are using Index instead..

Comment: Yeah that is one the mistake and the other mistake is i missed composer.json file while creating a module,Now it got rectified thanks for the help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below files and module structure for sample admin module

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mycompany_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Mycompany_Mymodule::parent" title="Mymodule" module="Mycompany_Mymodule" sortOrder="100" resource="Mycompany_Mymodule::parent"/>
        <add id="Mycompany_Mymodule::index" title="Mymodule Index" module="Mycompany_Mymodule" sortOrder="10" action="mymodule/index" resource="Mycompany_Mymodule::index" parent="Mycompany_Mymodule::parent"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="Mycompany_Mymodule" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHellowword()
    {
        return 'Demo Hellowword';
    }
}
?>
```

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\view\adminhtml\layout\mymodule_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Mycompany Page Title</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" name="mymodule_block_adminhtml_index_index"  template="Mycompany_Mymodule::mymodule_index_index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Mycompany\Mymodule\view\adminhtml\templates\mymodule_index_index.phtml

```
<?php 
echo $block->getHellowword();
?>
```

and don't forget to create **composer.json** and **registration.php** in your module's root

and you can access your module by adding **mymodule/index/index** after admin base URL.

Comment: Yeah @VDC followed your process of creating modules It works fine now...My mistake is I missed **composer.json** file . I've read many of the tutorials none of them speaks about composer.json file only now i got to know this..Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gokulpriya My Pleasure

Answer (score 0):

First create routes.xml file under

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="module" frontName="module">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Now create controller file like:

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Extension/Index

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Extension;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $resultPageFactory;



/**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
   * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
   */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

  /**
   * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/download_extension_index.xml
   *
   * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
   */
    public function execute()
    {
         return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Now create file like:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_module_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock" name="vendor_module_block" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally create phtml file:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/custom.phtml

```
<H5>Hello<h5>
```

This may help for you.

Comment: My mistake is i missed composer.json file while creating a module,Now it got rectified thanks for the help and support.